# OpenShift Sandbox Add pipeline checkbox missing

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want to learn the basics so I'm trying to deploy an app from a repository and add a pipeline, just like it's described here (3.1.4, point 8): https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.13/html-single/building_applications/index#odc-importing-codebase-from-git-to-create-application_odc-creating-applications-using-developer-perspective

However, I don't see the option to add a pipeline and the whole Pipelines section is missing. Not sure why that is: me doing something wrong, documentation being outdated, Sandbox not allowing that option, having to change some config beforehand etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the "Red Hat OpenShift Pipelines" operator?
On the console main page, between the "Build" and "Observe" menu (or between the "Builds" and "Helm" for the developper perspective), do you see the "Pipelines" menu?

It seems the pipeline operator is not installed, if not, install it:

- Operators > OperatorHub
- Search for "pipelines"
- Install the "Red Hat OpenShift Pipelines" operator

Comment: The Sandbox environment came with that operator installed out of the box. I can build pipelines through Pipelines section. However, there's no option to add one when I want to deploy an app through "Import from Git" option.